# PCA on integers or floating numbers: is there any difference?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, computer-vision

I want to use PCA to reduce SIFT (`128` dims) and VLAD vectors (`128*k` dims, let's say `k={64, 128, 256}`) dimensions as described in [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5432202/) paper.

SIFT descriptors can have integer values (by default in VLFeat) or float numbers (by default in OpenCV). In both cases, SIFT vecotrs have always positive values, while VLAD vectors could have negative values too.

Is there any performance reason (in terms accuracy or computation time) why I should prefer integer over floating numbers (or viceversa)?

Comment: In terms of accuracy you will almost certainly lose information when using integer arithmetic instead of floating point. That said, using less precise measurements does mean (in principal) that you can compute things faster (eg. when  writing some C++ code if you use `float` instead of `double` variables you immediately get some speed-up (in most cases) at the expense of less accurate results). Please note that the paper you link does not at any point refer to *integers*. Vector quantisation just refers to mapping to a smaller set. Cool paper though!

Comment: @usεr11852 I'm sorry, but I think you misunderstood my point of using "integers": I'm not talking about truncating or approximating `float` values into `int` values. I'm talking about to use different option for the SIFT algorithm in order to produce integer descriptors instead of floating ones. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038881/sift-descriptors-values-opencv-vs-vlfeat) question for more details. In addition, I dont understand why with less precise values you should get faster code. In addition, `double` is 8B, while `float` is 4B, so it should be the opposite.

Comment: Finally, I posted the linked paper because it talks about using PCA for reducing SIFT and VLAD descriptors, not benefits of PCA from integers.

Comment: Ooops my bad then regarding SIFT! Regarding the faster code: in the case of `float` you account for 4B while in the case of `double` you account for 8. Clearly you do less computations in the case of `float`. That's what I say. Obviously you will have less precision because of the increased round-off errors.